# Instalation issue

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php

I have the following error by installing *spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks* whit composer
after trying to downgrade composer version or remove some packages , could't resolve the problem

```html
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks[2.0.0].
    - spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks 2.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^8.29).


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Already try to install all available version of this pakage but without success.

Here is my composer.json file:

```html
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "illuminate/console": "^8.29",
        "illuminate/support": "^8.29",
        "laravel/cashier": "^12.9",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Have somepne experience whit problem like this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear to you? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of in `spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks` the `illuminate/support`  version required as `~5.8.0` which conflicts with your `composer.json` `illuminate/support` version (you can check it in the package v2.0.0 [Link](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks/blob/2.0.0/composer.json))

You can upgrade it to v2.5.0 (current last release) which requires `"illuminate/support": "^6.0|^7.0|^8.0"`, and its satisfiable with your version `"illuminate/support": "^8.29"`.

To do that just call `composer require spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks`